# Can I submit a pull request from GitLab.com to GitHub?

Tags: github, gitlab, pull-request

Most of our work occurs on GitLab.com (i.e. not a local GitLab installation). If the upstream repo resides on GitHub, is there a way to submit a pull request to upstream? (If forking the upstream repo in a particular way is part of solution, that's ok.)

Comment: These are called federated pull/merge requests. Both [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4013) and [Gitea](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/184) plan to support them, but GitHub never signaled similar intent.

Comment: @StevenRoose I look forward to a gitlab/gitea flavour of this question once they support ForgeFed :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No. The correct workflow would be forking the upstream project on GitHub to your own namespace. Then use your fork as upstream in your GitLab repository not the origin of your fork.

From your GitLab repository you are then pushing changes to your fork (upstream). Then on GitHub you can submit a pull request from your GitHub fork to the origin.

Answer (score 2):

This is **weird** but this is how I do it!

I have a repository on [Github](https://github.com/abranhe/ci-success/) but I wanted to use the [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/abranhe/ci-success/) CI, so I mirrored the repository from **Github** to **Gitlab**, then I configured the CI etc... I was looking around online, and I found that with Gitlab Enterprise you have [the feature](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/10/feature-highlight-push-to-remote-repository/) of pushing changes to an external repository from **GitLab**, but since I don't pay for Gitlab Enterprise, I did the following:

Since we are using [GIT](https://git-scm.com/), and we <s>are good programmers</s> try to be good programmers make it work, so:

**I JUST EDITED THE GIT URL**

How was it?

- Clone your repository
- Go to your project ...
- Navigate to `.git` **>** `config` and you should have something like this:

  [image: .git/config file]

Change the **URL** from **Github** to **Gitlab** (I had the same username and project name, in both services so, I only changed the URL).

Then, with the **Gitlab** URL:

```
$ git pull origin
```

Since the remote URL have changed, you should get the changes from **Gitlab**.

- Change again your remote URL back again to **Github**

Then push your changes:

```
$ git push origin
```

You should be done! Hope it works for you, it worked for me!

Comment: interesting approach - I guess you could create two named remotes, "github" and "gitlab", and `git pull gitlab` then `git push github`

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no way to do this with Microsoft GitHub.

Instead, you'll need to:

1. Create a GitHub repository
2. Add the GitHub remote:

   - SSH: `git remote add gh git@github.com:org/repo.git`
   - HTTPS: `git remote add gh https://github.com/org/repogit`
3. `git push gh master`
4. Create the pull request from your GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

No, MS github does not allow it and probably never will.

Of course, the upstream maintainer could add your fork as a remote and cherrypick from it or something, but that is more work than dealing with pull-requests. Hence few maintainers will be willing to do it.

Another way: The owner mirrors his project on gitlab. Then gitlab users can fork that and submit patches. This also is more work than dealing with a single project on MS github only and might be more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Kai and christianbundy's answers, I think the easiest way to do this is to

1. On Github, fork the repository into your own namespace.
2. In Gitlab, import the project, either using the [Github import](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html) utility or simply by creating from an existing repo.
3. In your local repository, set up all three remotes... let's call them origin, fork, and gitlab. Assuming origin is already your remote:
   `git remote add fork my/forked/github/url`
   `git remote add gitlab my/gitlab/url`
4. When you want to make your changes, create a local branch, and set the gitlab remote as your remote-tracking branch (continue making your changes on this branch until satisfied).
   `git push -u gitlab my-dev-branch`
5. When you are done developing, push your branch to your forked repo (on Github).
   `git push -u fork my-dev-branch`
6. When you do this, in the console output, there should be a link to make a pull request out of your new branch. Click it. By default, this should create a pull request targeting the master branch of the original repo. Fill out the page it redirects you to and you should be done!